# Python large iterations number fail

Tags: python, parallel-processing, iteration, montecarlo, pi

I wrote simple [monte-carlo π calculation](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/montecarlopimod.html) program in Python, using multiprocessing module.
It works just fine, but when I pass 1E+10 iterations for each worker, some problem occur, and the result is wrong. I cant understand what is the problem, because everything is fine on 1E+9 iterations!

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import random


def calculate_pi(iters):
    """ Worker function """

    points = 0  # points inside circle

    for i in iters:
        x = random()
        y = random()

        if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 1:
            points += 1

    return points


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: python pi.py workers_number iterations_per_worker"
        exit()

    procs = int(sys.argv[1])
    iters = float(sys.argv[2])  # 1E+8 is cool

    p = Pool(processes=procs)

    total = iters * procs
    total_in = 0

    for points in p.map(calculate_pi, [xrange(int(iters))] * procs):
        total_in += points

    print "Total: ", total, "In: ", total_in
    print "Pi: ", 4.0 * total_in / total
```

Comment: What is the wrong result you're getting?

Comment: @AmirRachum π is like ~0.4 total number of iterations is correct.

Comment: does this happen regardless of what `procs` is? what sort of values are you using for `procs`?

Comment: Why is iters a float rather than an int? What does it mean to have, say, 10000.0001 iterations?

Comment: @MattiLyra there is no division by `procs` number. So it should not. I'll test it later.
@abarnert for exponent. 1E+NUM is useful.

Comment: `int` can't parse `1E+8`

Comment: could your provide `print sys.argv[1:], xrange(int(float(sys.argv[2])))` for `sys.argv` that produces the wrong result?

Comment: @scrat No I wasn't thinking that, but that you exhaust `random.random()` as that is shared by all processes, although that's fairly unlikely as the period is `2**19937-1`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `['4', '1E+10'] xrange(10000000000)`

Comment: @MattiLyra: Yes, but if you give it a number that isn't exactly an integer (including if you try to give it an integer that isn't exactly representable as a float), then `total` ends up wrong, and therefore `total_in / total` is also wrong. So, it would be better to do `iters = int(float(sys.argv[2]))` in the first place. That didn't turn out to be the problem here, but it could.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem seems to be that multiprocessing has a limit to the largest int it can pass to subprocesses inside an xrange. Here's a quick test:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
def doit(n):
  print n
if __name__ == "__main__":
  procs = int(sys.argv[1])
  iters = int(float(sys.argv[2]))
  p = Pool(processes=procs)
  for points in p.map(doit, [xrange(int(iters))] * procs):
    pass
```

Now:

```
$ ./multitest.py 2 1E8
xrange(100000000)
xrange(100000000)
$ ./multitest.py 2 1E9
xrange(1000000000)
xrange(1000000000)
$ ./multitest.py 2 1E10
xrange(1410065408)
xrange(1410065408)
```

This is part of a more general problem with multiprocessing: It relies on standard Python pickling, with some minor (and not well documented) extensions to pass values. Whenever things go wrong, the first thing to check is that the values are arriving the way you expected.

In fact, you can see this problem by playing with `pickle`, without even touching `multiprocessing` (which isn't always the case, because of those minor extensions, but often is):

```
>>> pickle.dumps(xrange(int(1E9)))
'c__builtin__\nxrange\np0\n(I0\nI1000000000\nI1\ntp1\nRp2\n.'
>>> pickle.dumps(xrange(int(1E10)))
'c__builtin__\nxrange\np0\n(I0\nI1410065408\nI1\ntp1\nRp2\n.'
```

Even without learning all the details of the pickle protocol, it should be obvious that the `I1000000000` in the first case is 1E9 as an int, while the equivalent chunk of the next case is about 1.41E9, not 1E10, as an int. You can experiment

One obvious solution to try is to pass `int(iters)` instead of `xrange(int(iters))`, and let `calculate_pi` create the `xrange` from its argument. (Note: In some cases an obvious transformation like this can hurt performance, maybe badly. But in this case, it's probably slightly better if anything—a simpler object to pass, and you're parallelizing the `xrange` construction—and of course the difference is so tiny it probably won't matter. Just make sure to think before blindly transforming.)

And a quick test shows that this now works:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

def doit(n):
  print xrange(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    procs = int(sys.argv[1])
    iters = int(float(sys.argv[2]))
    p = Pool(processes=procs)
    for points in p.map(doit, [iters] * procs):
      pass
```

Then:

```
$ ./multitest.py 2 1E10
xrange(10000000000)
xrange(10000000000)
```

However, you will still run into a larger limit:

```
$ ./multitest.py 2 1E100
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Again, it's the same basic problem. One way to solve that is to pass the arg all the way down as a string, and do the int(float(a)) inside the subprocesses.

As a side note: The reason I'm doing `iters = int(float(sys.argv[2]))` instead of just `iters = float(sys.argv[2])` and then using `int(iters)` later is to avoid accidentally using the float `iters` value later on (as the OP's version does, in computing `total` and therefore `total_in / total`).

And keep in mind that if you get to big enough numbers, you run into the limits of the C double type: `1E23` is typically 99999999999999991611392, not 100000000000000000000000.

Comment: So why does 1000000000 iterations give you the correct PI estimate but 1410065408 iterations doesn't?

Comment: @MattiLyra: As a first guess, if you're doing 1410065408 iterations but think you're doing 1000000000 you're going to end up dividing wrong at the end. But I haven't tested or really thought it through.

Comment: In python 2.7.3 I get `>>> pickle.dumps(xrange(int(1E10))) OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long` in pyhton 3.2.3 I get `>>> pickle.dumps(range(int(1E10)),protocol=0)
b'c__builtin__\nxrange\np0\n(L0L\nL10000000000L\nL1L\ntp1\nRp2\n.'`

Comment: @XavierCombelle: It's not just about 2.7.3 vs. 3.2.3; it's also about 32-bit vs. 64-bit, different platforms and compilers, etc. If all numbers in your range happen to work on your implementation, you can ignore the problem (unless you might want a larger range or more portability later); otherwise, you have to deal with it.

Comment: In python 2.7.3 under Ubunutu 32 bits it doesn't exactly work it fails loud. I wonder exactly which version fail silently.

Comment: @XavierCombelle: It fails silently in the stock 64-bit python 2.7.2 on Mountain Lion. My guess is it'll probably do the same on 2.7 on any platform where a C long is 64 bits but a C int is 32 bits (so, e.g., 64-bit Mac or linux, but not Win64, or any 32-bit platform). Of course to be sure I'd have to either test a bunch of platforms or read the source.

Comment: This issue is tracked into python core development http://bugs.python.org/issue16029